# TCP and Wireshark: Two consecutive TCP packets instead of having an ACK for each of them

Tags: tcp, wireshark, ack, chunked

We have an application (client and server), deployed in two different environments (staging and production). Both environments are theoretically configured exactly... The client is sending data in a POST request, and the server is returning a 200 OK with a body.

In the first image [1], the client has the IP 172.16.32.47 and the server 172.16.44.137. You can see that before each 200 HTTP packet (in green), for example, frame 124, there is an ACK from the client to the packet in frame 122.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX76W.png

In the second image [2], the client has the IP 172.16.85.38 and the server has the IP 172.16.74.168. In this case, there are consecutive packets, for example, frames 422 and 423 from the server to the client, without an ACK in between.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF5an.png

In the first image, the TCP window is enough to send both frames without having to wait for the intermediate ACK (it's true that window size is bigger in the second image, but both should cover the message).

Why the ACK is being expected from the server and sent from the client in the first image? What should I take into account in order to make a deeper revision?

Any tip is really welcome.

Comment: You should check the Window of the client instead, at packet 120.

Comment: This is not about programming, therefore it's off-topic for StackOverflow.  It would be on-topic in SE's [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site. Anyway, my guess is that the server that waits for the client's ACK does not have the NODELAY option set on the connection, therefore the [Nagle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) forces the server's second response segment to be held back instead of being transmitted immediately. BTW, the two image links in the question are swapped.

Comment: Hi @ottomeister, thank you, I have already swapped the image links. None of the servers have the NODELAY option on the connections...

Comment: It doesn't matter. Both are legal. You just have to cope.

Comment: @EugèneAdell, at packet 120 the TCP window is 64296 (Window Size value and Calculated Window Size). Thank you.

Comment: Well, it sure looks like Nagle combined with a 40ms ACK delay at the receiver (which is a strange timeout value).  If the servers are running on Windows then it's possible that NODELAY could be turned on for one of the servers by the Registry, even if the server app does not ask for it. Windows supports a per-NIC "TcpNoDelay" setting at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{UUID-of-NIC}\TcpNoDelay`.

Comment: Hi, thank you again. Both servers in both deployments are Linux based. But in any case, what could explain the second image where no intermediate ACK is found?